# Perform a 3-way text merge in Node using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge

Does anyone know an efficient library or algorithm to automatically perform a best guess 3-way text merge in Node? I suppose that would be performing a rebase? (not sure if that is the right terminology).

I have two files modified from one root file -- a `BASE` a `1st File` and a `2nd File`, and I need to combine them together. It will throw an error if there is a conflict, or return the combined text if not. I looked around but could not locate a suitable library.